# Wrap first word in string in HTML tag with PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a string, for example `"Hello World"`.

This would be a variable, so I don't know the contents of the string, just that it will have a space.

What would be the best way to achieve this

`"<span>Hello</span> World"` from the original string `"Hello World"`?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at PHP's string functions? Tried anything at all?

Comment: @ficuscr You're correct, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use explode, implode and array_slice.
Explode and implode splits or joins a string to or from an array.
Array_slice takes a number of items in an array.
In this case I span the first item then the rest of the array are joint with space.

```
$string = "hello world. Hello world";
$words = explode(' ', $string);

$html = '<span>' . $words[0] . '</span> ' . Implode(" ", array_slice($words,1));

Echo $html;
```

https://3v4l.org/oTORH

No need for loops or memory hungry regex.

Comment: Also no need for hungry `explode()` making more than two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you're just wrapping the first word in a span:

```
$segments = explode(' ', $string);

$html = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($segments); $i++) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        $html .= '<span>' . $segments[$i] . '</span>';  
        continue;
    } 

    $html .= ' ' . $segments[$i];
}
```

Comment: Too many elements are produced in this explosion (or could be if the input had more words).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regexp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$changed = preg_replace('/^(\w+)/isux', '<span>$1</span>', $str);
```

Comment: The `i`, `s`, and `x` pattern modifiers provide no benefit to the pattern -- they are useless.  The capture group is also useless -- just use the fullstring match.